# How to implement com.objectspace.jgl package?

Tags: java, objectspace

I downloaded a code from internet which uses the following code

```
import com.objectspace.jgl.*;
import com.objectspace.jgl.Array;
import com.objectspace.jgl.algorithms.Shuffling;
import com.objectspace.jgl.algorithms.Sorting;
import com.objectspace.jgl.BinaryPredicate;
```

I have searched on internet but I am unable to find the jgl package.
If anyone can help me find the package or the methods included in those packages, it would be of great help. any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.recursionsw.com/products/JGL/JGL-toolkit-overview.html but it's a commercial jar

Comment: @rc thanks for the link. Well, I cant afford to buy the toolkit. So is there any way I can implement those methods in order to run the code?

Comment: Feel free to code them, javadoc might help: http://www.cs.duke.edu/csl/docs/jgl/api/Package-COM.objectspace.jgl.html

Comment: @RC. - Neither of your links work anymore. I have a project that relies on these classes, but it seems impossible to actually get them anymore - I get the idea that they were made by some insignificant company that went bellyup over a decade ago.

Comment: 1st link gives a 404, then Product menu to > http://www.recursionsw.com/jgl-toolkit-overview/